# Calling A Function With Different Names

Tags: python, function, variables

So I use a bunch of files. Each file will trigger when lets say variable x = function. I know this is confusing but pretty much I need to be able to use a variable name which depending on what the variable is equal to will call that function. I am using python for this.

Comment: Please add you code. The issue is not clear.

Comment: I don't have code. What I am trying to do is call a function with the string in a variable.

Comment: You don't want to do that. You want to use a `dict` that maps from some string name to the corresponding function.

Comment: You better have something if you are asking for help here.

Comment: I have code, just not for this part.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Please explain your idea.

Comment: I mean, you know what a dict is?

Comment: The function to call is determined by the variable name or the variable value?

Comment: @Mike67 Variable value.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No I do not

Comment: I would suggest the OP read this guide (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for pointers on what the community needs in order to offer good answers.  I also feel the need to point out while there may be means to embed a function call directly into the contents of a string variable, this comes with security concerns and can make your code difficult to maintain. I would strongly recommend studying Python Dictionaries, as recommended by Mr. Knechtel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, it looks like you want some sort of factory where the function to call is determined by the value of the variable passed in.

Here's a simple way of doing it:

```
x = 2  # determines which function to call

# possible functions to call 
def f0(p): print('called f0',p)
def f1(p): print('called f1',p)
def f2(p): print('called f2',p)
def f3(p): print('called f3',p)

lstFunc = [f0, f1 ,f2, f3]  # create list of functions

lstFunc[x]('test')  # x=2, call function at index 2 (f2)
```

Output

```
called f2 test
```

For something more complicated, you would use a function which returns another function based on the variable value. In this example, I'm just using a list of functions.